# Text edit toolbar solution (js), with low-level customization?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, textbox, toolbar

I'm looking for a js text edit toolbar, which allows for customization of base functions.

The best example is: Our platform employs a custom text parsing engine, and we use custom tags. Custom tags, even for basics like bold, etc. Therefore, I will need to change existing base formatting buttons to use our tags as opposed to html.

I have not been able to locate a solution, which allows the customization of these basic buttons. I can, of course use something mainstream, and rebuild all the base functionality in custom buttons. However, before doing that, I want to make sure there is not something already available.

Do you know of a solution which supports low level customization?

Comment: Is it a very custom parser, or is it still an XML dialect?

Answer (score 0):

You can have look at this one: https://github.com/bergie/hallo